# Is this Shortcut even possible?

Tags: iphone, shortcut, cellular-data, shortcuts-app

Apple (iPhone) has a tracker of your mobile data usage. One can access it through Settings > Mobile Data. Which shows you how much of the gb from your mobile plan had been used.

So the shortcut which im trying to create is: Each 1st of a month, to reset the Mobile Data Statistics.

Is it possible to make such a shortcut for iPhone? And if so, How?